# CakePHP Uploader Plugin - Saving multiple sizes with Behavior setup

Tags: plugins, cakephp-2.0, behavior, uploader

I'm trying to use the `Uploader` plug-in as `Behavior` of the `User` model I'm using on my web application. I've used it with the configuration I named `filename` as I show here:

```
<?php
class Avatar extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Avatar';
    public $actsAs = array (
        'Uploader.Attachment' => array (
            'filename' => array (
                'name'        => 'setNameAsImgId',
                'saveAsFilename' => true,
                'uploadDir'    => '/files/avatars/160/',
                'dbColumn'    => 'filename',
                'defaultPath'    => 'default.png',
                'maxNameLength'    => 20,
                'overwrite'    => true,
                'stopSave'    => true,
                'allowEmpty'    => false,
                'transforms'    => array (
                    array('method' => 'resize', 'width' => 160, 'height' => 160, 'dbColumn' => 'filename', 'append' => false, 'overwrite' => true)
                )
            )
        )
    );
// and so on...
?>
```

This configuration save the file to the folder `/files/avatars/160` where I keep all the images with the size of 160 pixels with this method via `Users` Controller:

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {

public function add () {
    if ($this->User->Avatar->save($this->request->data)) {
        // do some code...
    }
}
```

In the view `add` I'll insert this code to upload the file:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Avatar.filename', array('type' => 'file', 'label'=>'Upload the avatar '));
```

This works fine if I save just one configuration named `filename` as in the upper example, my problem is that I need to save different size and crops of the same image, so I would like to save a list of sizes like this:

```
/files/avatars/160/filename.jpg
/files/avatars/48/filename.jpg
```

To do this I thought to add another configuration to my `Avatar` model to this

```
<?php
class Avatar extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Avatar';
    public $actsAs = array (
        'Uploader.Attachment' => array (
            'filename' => array (
                'name'        => 'setNameAsImgId',
                'saveAsFilename' => true,
                'uploadDir'    => '/files/avatars/160/',
                'dbColumn'    => 'filename',
                'defaultPath'    => 'default.png',
                'maxNameLength'    => 20,
                'overwrite'    => true,
                'stopSave'    => true,
                'allowEmpty'    => false,
                'transforms'    => array (
                    array('method' => 'resize', 'width' => 160, 'height' => 160, 'dbColumn' => 'filename', 'append' => false, 'overwrite' => true)
                )
            ),
            'small' => array (
                'name'        => 'setNameAsImgId',
                'saveAsFilename' => true,
                'uploadDir'    => '/files/avatars/48/',
                'dbColumn'    => 'filename',
                'defaultPath'    => 'default.png',
                'maxNameLength'    => 20,
                'overwrite'    => true,
                'stopSave'    => true,
                'allowEmpty'    => false,
                'transforms'    => array (
                    array('method' => 'resize', 'width' => 48, 'height' => 48, 'dbColumn' => 'filename', 'append' => false, 'overwrite' => true)
                )
            )
        )
    );
// and so on...
?>
```

How should I set up the `UsersController` to save the multiple crops of the same image with `Avatar`?
Should I also change the `add` view to let it works?
I wouldn't use multiple input files in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
$this->Form->input('Avatar.filename.', array('type' => 'file', 'multiple');
```

As you see, I put a `.`, after the field name, and the *multiple* attribute. With that, you can do multiple uploads. So the result in `$this->request->data` is like this:

```
[Avatar] => array(
  ['filename'] => array(
    [0] => array(
      'name' => '...',
      'tmp_name' => '...',
      ...
    ),
    [1] => array(
      'name' => '...',
      'tmp_name' => '...',
      ...
    ),
    [2] => array(
      'name' => '...',
      'tmp_name' => '...',
      ...
    ),
    [3] => array(
      'name' => '...',
      'tmp_name' => '...',
      ...
    )
  )
)
```

Now you need change your behavior for use that with a simple **foreach**.

I hope this help you.

*Sorry for my english :)*